# Why objects in flask-sqlalchemy still show up as valid?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

After setting up two tables with the following code

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(Password)
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    studies = db.relationship('Study', backref='owner', lazy=True, cascade='save-update, merge, delete')

class Study(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    owner_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

I am testing that the removal of studies happens when the user gets removed. So far, seems to be the case, but I need to get to the database to discover that:

```py
def test_studies_removed_with_user(app):
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=app.config['TESTUSER_EMAIL']).first()
    study = Study(owner=user)

    db.session.add(study)
    db.session.commit()

    assert study

    db.session.delete(user)
    db.session.commit()

    assert User.query.filter_by(email=app.config['TESTUSER_EMAIL']).first() is None
    assert not Study.query.filter_by(owner_id=user.id).all()
```

if I break with the debugger in the prior to last assert, user variable is still populated, and so is study. I'd have expected these variables to be invalid now (because the asserts succeed, even the second which uses id from 'user', so the entries are removed on the database).

Is this expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is expected.  Deleting the database entry has no effect on the python variable.  To make an analogy, it's like you took a photo of a piece of wood and then threw the piece of wood in a fire and it burned up.  The photo still exists; destroying the wood had no effect on the photo.

Comment: Or, to put it another way, the python variable represents the database object _as it was when it was fetched from the database_.  There is no ongoing future relationship between those two things.  The python variable is a one-time snapshot of the database object.